# How to execute mulitple suites parallely with TestNG

Tags: ant, testng

Im able to execute above suites sequentially but i want to parallel execution of these suites.

```
please find the xml 
 <suite name="Main suite"  > <!--commenting parallel="suite-file" thread-count="2"-->
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="suite1.xml" />
     <suite-file path="suite2.xml" />
      </suite-files>
    </suite>
```

Comment: <suite name="Main suite"  > <!--commenting parallel="suite-file" thread-count="2"-->
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="suite1.xml" />
    <suite-file path="suite2.xml" />
    </suite-files>
    
</suite>

Comment: You should put the code under the question, not it a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Pls refer TestNG documentation here:

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running

For running suites in parallel:

```
java org.testng.TestNG -suitethreadpoolsize 2 suite1.xml suite2.xml
```

For running tests/classes/methods/instances define it in testng xml

```
<suite name="Main suite" parallel="methods/classes/tests/instances" thread-count="5">
```

Comment: 2 questions:  
**#1** What will happen if for `java org.testng.TestNG -suitethreadpoolsize 10 suite1.xml suite2.xml `? Suite thread pool size is 10 but the suite files are just 2.  **#2** Can the `thread-count in suite > suitethreadpoolsize`?

Comment: @AayushKumarSingha for #1 you are allocating 10 threads but only 2 are utilized. TestNG handles how many threads to be created based on the pending suites/tests/methods to be executed.  This situation arises in normal cases as well. Think that you have 10 methods to execute and you have a thread pool size of 3, assuming all tests end at same time, you will have 1 method pending.  TestNG will then close other two threads and operate on only one thread. After all methods are exhausted, threads will be closed.

Comment: @AayushKumarSingha for #2 question, I haven't tried that configuration. My guess TestNG operates in SuiteThreadPools * Thread-count and creates that many threads.  I usually don't go that route, but create multiple Jenkins jobs.  Let me know here, if you try the configuration and any learnings from it.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810342/is-there-a-possible-way-to-run-two-xml-files-in-testng-xml-parallel/26858328#26858328) that may be of some help to you.  You're on the right track using the suite-of-suites XML configuration.

It's been quite some time since I've worked with this type of configuration, but what I posted in that answer was how I was able to get it to work in parallel.  Other approaches likely exist, but hopefully this will get you started.